# SignalR 2.2.0 'Context.ConnectionId' .Net client cannot be set manually

Tags: c#, signalr

When I do:

```
Connection = new HubConnection(uri);
Connection.ConnectionId = "89668c32-c654-40a2-96c3-21a888f31c9f";
Connection.Start(new LongPollingTransport())
```

The second line does nothing, and my hub sees a different Id each time.  Any ideas?

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue.  I see the set ConnectionId each time.  Can you provide a more complete example?

Comment: Are you using LongPollingTransport()?

Comment: What's the scenario here? Connection id is assigned by the server when the client connects so how would you know what to set it to on the client?

Comment: I need to have have persistent Id so that my groups are maintained after the clients disconnect

Comment: When you start a new connection the server creates a new connection id. If you send a message with a different connection id the server should/would reject the request since it would not recognize the client id after the client disconnects. On top of that you would also need to send a connection token created by the server. If you don't send a valid connection token the request will fail. SignalR protocol is described: http://blog.3d-logic.com/2015/03/29/signalr-on-the-wire-an-informal-description-of-the-signalr-protocol/ - it contains a link to an article explaining how connection token works

Answer (score 1):

Connection Ids are assigned and tracked by the server. The client receives the connection id during connection negotiation. In addition to the connection id the during connection negotiation the client receives a connection token that is calculated on the server (you can find more details about connection negotiation and SignalR protocol in general in [this blog post](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2015/03/29/signalr-on-the-wire-an-informal-description-of-the-signalr-protocol/)). The connection token is calculated using the name of the user and connection id and is then encrytped. The client has to send the connection token in each request. If the client does not send the connection token or the connection token send by the client does not match the encrypted data that connection will be rejected (more on connection tokens [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/security/introduction-to-security#connectiontoken)). As a result even though you could probably hack this within your environment by reusing a connection Id/connection token the server knows about setting connection id on the client is not a supported scenario and in reality the ConnectionId property should probably not even have the setter (in fact [IConnection.ConnectionId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.iconnection.connectiontoken(v=vs.118).aspx) property has only a getter).